# Jqplot multiline ticks/labels

Tags: jquery, jqplot

I am trying to break long label/ticks of `jqPlot` charts into multiline using '`<br>`' or `\n` but all in vain. Can anyone suggest what is the problem?

Which is the best way to break labels into multiline?

```
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jqPlot/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jqPlot/jqplot.barRenderer.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jqPlot/jqplot.highlighter.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jqPlot/jqplot.cursor.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jqPlot/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jqPlot/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jqPlot/jqplot.canvasTextRenderer.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jqPlot/jqplot.pointLabels.min.js"></script>
  <script id="example_1" type="text/javascript">    
     $(document).ready(function () {
         var line1 = [5600, 3150, 18];
         var ticks = ['Hardware <br /> and <br /> Installtion', 'Labor', 'Electricity'];    

         plot1 = $.jqplot('chart1', [line1], {
            title: 'Breakout total Cost of Ownership : LFD vs existing solution',
            animate: true,
            seriesColors: ['#1F497D', '#C0504D', '#9BBB59'],

            seriesDefaults: {
                renderer: $.jqplot.BarRenderer,
                rendererOptions: {
                    waterfall: true,
                    barWidth: 50,
                    animation:
                    {
                        speed: 2500
                    },
                    useNegativeColors: false,
                    varyBarColor: true
                },
                pointLabels: {
                    hideZeros: false
                },
                yaxis: 'yaxis',
                xaxis: 'x2axis',
                pointLabels: { show: true }
            },
            axes: {
                x2axis: {
                    renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                    ticks:ticks,
                    tickRenderer: $.jqplot.CanvasAxisTickRenderer,

                    tickOptions: {
                        fontFamily: 'Georgia',
                        fontSize: '8pt',
                        showGridline: true
                    }
                },
                yaxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    tickInterval: 20000,
                    tickOptions: {
                        formatString: "$%'d"
                    }
                }
            },
            cursor: {
                show: true
            }
        });
    });
 </script>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: That long tick is breaking up for me here http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/MF3zE/2/ :s

Comment: Check the JS files are being found

Answer (score 3):

After removing below line, it worked fine. Thanks

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jqPlot/jqplot.canvasAxisTickRenderer.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Apparently the canvas renderer doesn't support html line breaking as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/MF3zE/3/ @Joy and @ManseUK How to do line breaking when you use `canvasAxisTickRenderer` this case?

Comment: Note: Removing this plugin prevents setting the label at an angle so, its either you want to slant the label of have it on 2 lines..you choice ;)